# Xfce add to archive right menu item don't work

Tags: rhel, xfce, menu

I have RHEL for developers installed on my local machine with xfce. When I right-click on any file and select **add to archive** it says that there is no such program. **7zip** and **fileroller** are installed and if I manually do the same thing in the shell It works, but xfce don't want to.

How to point on correct archivator for xfce menu item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How to add custom *'Add to archive'* action in Xfce4 Thunar

if a default `thunar-archive-plugin` don't work properly

---

1. Uninstall `thunar-archive-plugin`:

   ```
   yum remove thunar-archive-plugin
   ```
2. In the `Thunar` menu open `Edit` ⇒ `Configure custom actions`. Add menu item `Add to archive`:

   - File name template:

     ```
     *
     ```
   - Command:

     ```
     file-roller "--default-dir=%D" --add %F
     ```
   - See screenshots:

     - Basic:

     [image: Action - Basic]

     - Appearance conditions:

     [image: Action - Appearance conditions]
   - Don't forget to add appropriate icon

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings > Mime Type Editor` and filter by archive (zip, rar, etcetra) and bind a program to it.

You have `7za` installed, not `7zip`. The former is windows only and the latter is CLI.

File-roller is adequate for most operations.